# Check from functions.php if function exists in footer.php

Tags: functions, footer, function-exists

I am trying to secure the copyrights links from `footer.php` file and I want to create a function in footer php which will have those links and then I want to check from functions.php if that function exists in the footer and in case it doesn't I would like to show an `exit();` function. I am also planning to encode the footer and functions php code.

I tried `function_exists()` but it works only if the function I am checking is in the same file as function_exists is. Can anybody give me any idea on how to solve this? Tank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare functions in your templates. The templates are for outputting content. The `function_exists()` will check if the function is declared ***before*** the `function_exists()` call, not after it, and templates are loaded after `functions.php` file, since you can control them by using the `template_redirect` filter.

Declare your function in your theme's `functions.php` file, and then call it in your template. This is the best way to go.